# Ruby Hash Group by two keys

Tags: ruby, group-by

I have a Ruby hash which looks like this-

```
report = {
    "count_by_state"=>[
        {"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>2, "count"=>48},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>3, "count"=>5},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>4, "count"=>89},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>2, "count"=>1},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>3, "count"=>4},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>4, "count"=>90}
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get a hash which looks like this

```
{2: {"2021-02-23" => 48,"2021-02-25" => 1},
3: {"2021-02-23" => 5,"2021-02-25" => 4},
4: {"2021-02-23" => 89,"2021-02-25" => 90}}
```

I have tried a bunch of things and have got so far with this code-

```
grouping = report['count_by_state'].group_by {|x| x['policy_state']}
puts grouping
puts grouping.map { |k,v| [ k => v.group_by {|x| x['day']} ] }

{2=>{"2021-02-23"=>[{"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>2, "count"=>48}], "2021-02-25"=>[{"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>2, "count"=>1}]}}
{3=>{"2021-02-23"=>[{"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>3, "count"=>5}], "2021-02-25"=>[{"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>3, "count"=>4}]}}
{4=>{"2021-02-23"=>[{"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>4, "count"=>89}], "2021-02-25"=>[{"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>4, "count"=>90}]}}
```

How can I get the values from day and count and create a value pair? I am trying to create a chart using squid and it uses data in a certain format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're grouping the result after the first group, but the hash content remains the same, you can use map to create a new hash only with the values you need:

```
report['count_by_state'].group_by { |count| count['policy_state'] }
                        .transform_values do |val|
                          val.to_h { |hash| hash.values_at('day', 'count') }
                        end
# {
# 2=>{"2021-02-23"=>48, "2021-02-25"=>1},
# 3=>{"2021-02-23"=>5,  "2021-02-25"=>4},
# 4=>{"2021-02-23"=>89, "2021-02-25"=>90}
# }
```

`to_h` is the short version of `map { |...| [x, y] }.to_h`, if your Ruby version doesn't support it  yet, you can use that.

Answer (score 3):

You could go straight to the result without going through `group_by` by using `each_with_object` and an auto-vivifying Hash:

```
report['count_by_state'].each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }) { |c, h| h[c['policy_state']][c['day']] = c['count'] }
```

If you really want Symbols as keys then:

```
report['count_by_state'].each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }) { |c, h| h[c['policy_state'].to_s.to_sym][c['day']] = c['count'] }
# or
report['count_by_state'].each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }) { |c, h| h[:"#{c['policy_state']}"][c['day']] = c['count'] }
```

If that sort of one-liner is too long for your taste then you can clarify it by naming the parts with methods and lambdas:

```
def auto_hash
  Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }
end

def extract_policy_states_from(report)
  set_day_counts = ->(c, h) { h[c['policy_state']][c['day']] = c['count'] }
  report['count_by_state'].each_with_object(auto_hash, &set_day_counts)
end
```

and just say `extract_policy_states_from(report)` to get the Hash you're after.

Comment: Although a good solution it's a bit cryptic due to the length of the line, and then nested block passed to `Hash.new` within the `each_with_object` argument. For readability I'd suggest extracting the parameter into a variable beforehand. Then use a normal `each` instead of `each_with_object`. (resulting in [this](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/74c7fca971aacd3089c9e5bb094b9305))

Comment: @3limin4t0r The block form of the Hash constructors does tend to be noisy and verbose but I'd refactor it differently and stay with `each_with_object` (whose main utility is its return value).

Answer (score 2):

```
def parse_report(report)
    recursive_default_proc = ->(h, k) {
        h[k] = Hash.new(&recursive_default_proc)
    }
    result = Hash.new(&recursive_default_proc)
    report["count_by_state"].each do |data|
        result[data["policy_state"]][data["day"]] = data["count"]
    end
    result
end

report = {
    "count_by_state"=>[
        {"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>2, "count"=>48},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>3, "count"=>5},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-23", "policy_state"=>4, "count"=>89},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>2, "count"=>1},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>3, "count"=>4},
        {"day"=>"2021-02-25", "policy_state"=>4, "count"=>90}
    ]
}

p parse_report(report)
# {
#  2=>{"2021-02-23"=>48, "2021-02-25"=>1}, 
#  3=>{"2021-02-23"=>5, "2021-02-25"=>4}, 
#  4=>{"2021-02-23"=>89, "2021-02-25"=>90}
# }
```

reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAn3c6O2OZo

Comment: That's interesting. Since your reference is a (31 minute) video it would be helpful to include the time into the video where the use of the recursive default is discussed. Better would be to provide an explanation in your answer or by providing a reference to a written explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
report["count_by_state"].each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["policy_state"]=>{g["day"]=>g["count"]}) {|_k,o,n| o.merge(n)}
end
  #=> {2=>{"2021-02-23"=>48, "2021-02-25"=>1},
  #    3=>{"2021-02-23"=>5, "2021-02-25"=>4},
  #    4=>{"2021-02-23"=>89, "2021-02-25"=>90}}
```

The block variables equal the following:

- `_k`: the common key. The underscore signals to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation.
- `o`: the value `h[_k]` of the ("old") hash that is being constructed by merging other hashes into it; and
- `n`: the value `{ g["day"]=>g["count"] }` of the ("new") hash `{ g["policy_state"]=>{ g["day"]=>g["count"] } }` that is being merged into the hash being constructed, `h`, when `_k == g["policy_state"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, maybe less obscure, is to map your data to very simple "one-case" versions of your result, and then merge them. This will work provided you don't have duplicate rows.

```
report['count_by_state']
  .map { |data| { data['policy_state'] => { data['day'] => data['count'] } } }
  .reduce { |this, that| this.merge(that) { |_, v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) } }
```

The first mapping would lead to

```
[{2=>{"2021-02-23"=>48}},
 {3=>{"2021-02-23"=>5}},
 {4=>{"2021-02-23"=>89}},
 {2=>{"2021-02-25"=>1}},
 {3=>{"2021-02-25"=>4}},
 {4=>{"2021-02-25"=>90}}]
```

which you can reduce on.